# Duplicate slice of pointers to structs with slightly different values

Tags: go, pointers, slice

Given two nested types

```
type Inner struct {
  InnerVal int
}

type Outer struct {
  InnerStruct *Inner
  OuterVal int
}
```

I need to duplicate a slice of pointers to `Outer`

```
originalSlice := []*Outer{<plenty_of_items>}
```

with itself, **but having updated field values** in the duplicates, including the `Outer.InnerStruct.InnerVal`.

To do so I create a new slice of the same type and length as `originalSlice`, append pointers to newly created structs with altered values to it, and finally append these items to the `originalSlice`

```
duplicateSlice := make([]*Outer, len(originalSlice))

for _, originalItem := range originalSlice {
  duplicateSlice = append(duplicateSlice, &Outer{
    InnerStruct: &Inner{
      InnerVal: originalItem.InnerStruct.InnerVal + 1
    },
    OuterVal: originalItem.OuterVal + 1,
  })
}

originalSlice = append(originalSlice, duplicateSlice...)
```

While this is verbose enough to follow the pointers around, or so I thought, when passed to a function right after as `nowDoubledSlice`, and accessed via loop

```
someOtherSlice := make([]*types.Inner, len(nowDoubledSlice))

for i, doubledItem := range nowDoubledSlice {
  someOtherSlice[i] = doubledItem.InnerStruct
}
```

I get a

> runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

Why is that? And is there a more elegant or idiomatic way to duplicate a slice of pointers to structs, while altering the duplicates' fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's nothing to do with your pointer creation, it's your slice allocation. This line:

```
duplicateSlice := make([]*Outer, len(originalSlice))
```

Creates a new slice of length `len(originalSlice)`, *filled with zero-value elements*. What you likely want instead is:

```
duplicateSlice := make([]*Outer, 0, len(originalSlice))
```

to create a slice of length `0` but *capacity* of `len(originalSlice)`. This works fine, [as you can see here](https://play.golang.org/p/kS1T7lO9J-u).

Alternatively, you could keep `make([]*Outer, len(originalSlice))` and use indexing instead of `append` in your loop:

```
for i, originalItem := range originalSlice {
    duplicateSlice[i] =&Outer{
        InnerStruct: &Inner{
            InnerVal: originalItem.InnerStruct.InnerVal + 1,
        },
        OuterVal: originalItem.OuterVal + 1,
    }
}
```

Which works just as well, [as you can see here](https://play.golang.org/p/7caBcLS5_J_9).

Comment: Uff...I will have a very private face palm moment with me now. Thank you for finally taking this off of me, I haven't seen the obvious after hours. Well written, compact answer within no time, too! i dare to accept this right away, and be done with it.